# Save PDF from external Server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, lumen, php-5.6

I have My client -> My Company System -> The Service Provider. It was suppose to be a simple task. My client sends me his id, I send it to my service provider which returns the pdf url. Then I get the PDF and send it to My Client attached by email.

The PDF is generated like `https://www.provider.com/mycompany/myclientid_somerandomshit.pdf` and it can be accessed by browser without any password.

Easy right? Just a

> file_get_contents("https://www.provider.com/mycompany/myclientid_somerandomshit.pdf");

Right? Nope. Not at all. It is returning the error

> ```
> Peer certificate CN=… did not match expected CN
> ```

Humm, not so easy. Let's do it by curl. A little bit more code, but it should work. Lets see... curl is asking for a path in order to save the file in my server. I don't want to download it, I want to attach it by e-mail.

Any idea on how to solve Peer certificate error, or get the file by curl without download it or do it in any other way???

Ps: My service provider takes too long to answer, and usually they are not helpfull, so any suggestions that envolves asking then anything it won't be good. Especially because the same task is done in another part of My System coded in Python using `urllib.urlopen(unicode("https://www.provider.com/mycompany/myclientid_somerandomshit.pdf")).read()`

Thank you in advance

Comment: do you need to add http:// to the file_get_contents ?

Comment: most mailer scripts will take a string as an attachment.

Comment: @tuckbloor I forgot to write it here, but it has https already

Comment: @smith

using 
->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($url)) returns

 "Unable to open file for reading [https://www.provider.com/mycompany/myclientid_somerandomshit.pdf]",

Comment: thats looking for a file, and presumably a local one, not a remote one.

Comment: And which code is equivalent for attach a remote file in swiftmailer?

Comment: When this happened to me. I've had to check if openssl was installed. And to add this line in my php.ini

openssl.cafile=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem

Comment: `Peer certificate CN=… did not match expected CN` means the site's security certificate is invalid. They will need to fix it. Modern PHP does not let you bypass security and accept a bad cert.

Comment: So I guess in this case there is no workaround. If the provider refuse to fix this I won't be able to deliver this task. Thank you @miken32

Comment: Thank you @Lou I've checked here and my openssl is enabled. :/

Comment: @miken32 was right. Now everything is working, Thank you all for helping me.